# question regarding oracle sysdate to last month date

Tags: database, oracle

```
OBSERVED_DATE BETWEEN add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) and last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1))
```

I need to run query between the 01-11-2019 to 30-11-2019 how do I change the sysdate to last month values

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dates may have non-zero time of day, it is best to write such conditions with explicit inequalities, rather than using `between`. Between is inclusive of both ends, when what you need (in almost all cases) is >= 1 November and < 1 December.

If, instead, you write <= 30 November (which is what you do when you use `between` the way you are trying now), you will miss everything from the last day of the month, 30 November, that has a time-of-day greater than midnight.

The `where` clause should look like this:

```
...
where observed_date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1)
  and observed_date <  trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
```

Still, if you insist on getting the last day of the previous month (such as 30 November) for whatever reason, that is simply

```
trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - 1
```

(that is, subtract one day from the first day of the *current* month).

Answer (score 0):

There is another function which returns last day of the month. I.e. `last_day`

So your condition should look like this:

```
where observed_date 
      between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1)
      and last_day(add_months(sysdate, -1))
```

Cheers!!